# Is there a way to make the get_post_meta() function work in this class?

Tags: php, wordpress, class, function

I am trying to make a class in PHP that will need to use a function from Wordpress, but the function doesn't work inside the class. Is there a way to make it work? Thanks!

```
class MetaData
{   
    private $key;

    public function __construct($key){
        $this->key = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, TRUE); 
    }
    public function getData(){
        print $this->key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$post` is a global variable, so you have to to explicitly state that:

```
public function __construct ($key) {
    global $post;
    $this->key = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, TRUE); 
}
```